# Unity 2D lines shader (Built_in RP)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to create a shader that draws multiple lines inside an object like this
[image]

Not exactly like this, but you get the idea. The width doesn't matter either, the line can be even 1 pixel thick.
So what I want to understand is how can I draw multiple instances of some geometry(?) in a 2d shader. Do i need to somehow modify the uvs? or is it some kind of instancing?